# Is there any guarantee on the size of an std::reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, reference-wrapper

Consider the case in which I've enough storage to host a `void *` and therefore to construct in-place a pointer.
Is there any guarantee that the same storage is big enough to always store also an `std::reference_wrapper`?

Kind of (written out of my mind, just to give a grasp of what I mean):

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(void *), alignof(void *)> storage;
// ...
int value = 0;
new (&storage) std::reference_wrapper<int>{value};
```

From a quick and dirty test, I see that on my machine this is valid, that is the size of an `std::reference_wrapper` fits with that of a `void *`. However it could be the case on different platforms. At the same time, I cannot find any clue in the standard about the size of and `std::reference_wrapper` and I'm wondering if it's implementation defined or there are any guarantees.

---

To give a context, I'm working on an opaque wrapper around different types (similar to `std::any`) that performs a small object optimization to avoid allocations when possible.
When I receive an `std::reference_wrapper`, I want to use a different path than that used to differentiate `sizeof(T) > sizeof(void *)` from the other case around. However, I don't know if I can just copy construct in-place the wrapper or if I should rely on allocations also in this case instead.

Comment: FWIW C++ doesn't even specify that a `void*` is the same size as all other pointers.  For instance a member function pointer can be larger than `void*`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cde0ef2f3d7dc3a

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed, but it says that you can assign a pointer to object to a `void *` while you cannot do the same with pointers to members. I wonder if it says also something like - _a wrapper cannot be larger than a pointer to the same object_. I don't think so but asking looks like a good strategy before to proceed. :-)

Comment: Datapoint: gcc's [current implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/refwrap.h) has `sizeof(std::reference_wrapper<T>) == sizeof(T*)` (although I agree with NathanOliver that this is not guaranteed)

Comment: Another datapoint: clang's [current implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/56bc01df8f4f30fe28f94f20b13c3e8e76c0cf71/include/__functional_base) also has `sizeof(std::reference_wrapper<T>) == sizeof(T*)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ standard does not pose any size requirements.  Per [[refwrap]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/refwrap)

> 1. `reference_­wrapper<T>` is a Cpp17CopyConstructible and Cpp17CopyAssignable wrapper around a reference to an object or function of type `T`.
> 2. `reference_­wrapper<T>` is a trivially copyable type.

All we know is that is copyable, and it is trivial.  Other than that it it left up to the implementation.  Typically it is just a wrapper for a `T*`, but the implementation might have some other members in there for some reason

Answer (score 8):

There is no guarantee in the standard.

No sensible implementation is going to use more than a pointer.

`static_assert` it fits and you have enough alignment so your code is correct (and people can see it is correct).  That static assert won't ever be hit.